# compile zlib by vs2013(64) on win7(64) get error

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, msbuild

In caffe installation, trying to compile(build solution) *zlib1.2.8* by *vs2013(64)* on win7(64) get error as below pic.

The default solution was opened in the

```
...\Desktop\zlib\contrib\vstudio\vc11\zlibvc.sln
```

The **error msg**:

> error MSB3073: The command "cd ....\contrib\masmx64 bld_ml64.bat
>   :VCEnd" exited with code 9009.    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 122 5   zlibvc

But running *bld_ml64.bat* in command line got no error.

Any suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same issue with zlib 1.2.8 on Windows 10 using VS2013 targeting x64.

I was able to get around it by the zlibvc.vcxproj:

In ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'"

Change:

```
<PreBuildEvent>
  <Command>cd ..\..\..\contrib\masmx64 
           bld_ml64.bat
  </Command>
</PreBuildEvent>
```

You also can make the command empty and bld_mlbat64.bat manually.